# Add md5 hash to Perl sub

Tags: perl, md5

How can a md5sum of a file be appended to the list of the output below. So the last entry would be *MD5=" . $md5*.

```
106         sub generate_file_hash(){
107            my $filename = shift;
108
109            $MASTERCOUNT++;
110
111            my ($devs, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev,
112                 $size, $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat($filename);
113
114            open(FILE, $filename) or die "Can't open '$filename': $!";
115            binmode(FILE);
116            $md5 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile(*FILE)->hexdigest();
117
118            return($filename . ",PERMISSIONS=" . $devs  . ",INODE=" . $ino  .
119                           ",MODE=" . $mode  . ",HARD LINKS=" .
120                           $nlink . ",UID=" . $uid  . ",GID=" . $gid  .
121                           ",DEVICE=" . $rdev  . ",SIZE=" .
122                           $size . ",LAST MODIFIED=" .  $mtime  .
123                           ",INODE CREATED=" . $ctime  . ",BLOCK SIZE=" .
124                           $blksize . ",BLOCKS=" . $blocks . ",MD5=" . $md5);
125         }
```

<strike>Errors:</strike>

<strike>Global symbol "$md5" requires explicit package name at integritychk line 116.</strike>
    <strike>Global symbol "$md5" requires explicit package name at integritychk line 124.</strike>

Currently the output is:

```
/etc/group,PERMISSIONS=51712,INODE=565260,MODE=33188,HARD LINKS=1,UID=0,GID=0,DEVICE=0,SIZE=595,LAST MODIFIED=1273887035,INODE CREATED=1273887035,BLOCK SIZE=4096,BLOCKS=8
```

So the MD5 value of the file would be appended.

Comment: Your program is running using `strict` (which is good.) You need to declare variables with `my` before using them. So `my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new....` will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Digest::MD5;

open(FILE, $filename) or die "Can't open '$filename': $!";
binmode(FILE);
my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new->addfile(*FILE)->hexdigest();
```

Read the [`Digest::MD5` manpage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Digest%3a%3aMD5) for more info on various ways to use the module.

Comment: Getting errors noted above, I included _use Digest::MD5;_ at beginning of file.